# Div obstructing onmousemove function - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, onmousemove

I'm trying to create a magnifier application in javascript.
So, when I hover over an image a part of that image is displayed in a corner, and on the existing image, a div is displayed, showing me which area I magnify. See what I'm talking about on [this link](http://www.mega.co.rs/magnifier.php).
Unfortunately, that div is obstructing my onmousemove fuction that updates the coordinates of my magnified image, and so I get a laggy response...

Is there any solution to this problem? If somebody wants to see the code, just let me know...

Answer (score 0):

Give the obstructing div this CSS:

```
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
z-index: 9999;
```

Give those attributes to `.info-cd`.

Comment: The div already has those attributes. The problem is when the div is positioned, my onmousemove function doesn't trigger smoothly because my cursor is not on the image anymore, its on the div...

Comment: If the `div` already has those attributes, it will not obstruct! Try giving a higher `z-index`.

Comment: I don't think the z-index is the problem.. I need my cursor to somehow be on the image at all times when it is in the coordinate range... so setting the z-index of the image to be higher than the z-index of the div would solve the problem... kinda. Then the div wouldn't be visible...

Comment: Ha ha ha... Give some space then! `:)` Make the image display beneath the height of the div.

Comment: Yes, but the div then loses it's point... I'm setting it so that I could see the area that's being magnified. :/

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is your `ajax` call on `mouseover`, it keeps sending requests. Open your page and try this in your console and you'll see it doesn't lag anymore:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('img')[0].onmouseover = function(){return false}
readData();
```

You still have a flickering problem, but it shouldn't be to hard to solve.

As for your ajax request, maybe it would be safer to call it on load, or at least remove it from `onmouseover` once it's been completed once.